# When should I request clearance to return to altitude, after leaving cruise altitude?

Tags: radio-communications

I can not understand the term”cruise” perfectly.
I know I should request ATC clearance to return to cruise altitude, if I leave cruise altitude to out side of the block.

Ex) Cleared cruise altitude 6000, MEA is 4000. The block is between 4000 to 6000. So I can descent or climb within the block without clearance. if I leave to out of block, i need ATC clearance for return to the block altitude

There are two which I am confused.
First, Can I descent/climb several times without clearance within the block or just once is possible?

Second, When I leave assigned within the block, still should I request an

[image]

Comment: Your question is incomplete, it says "still should I request an".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “cruise” terminology you are questioning is really not used anymore. It still appears in manuals, but it was very confusing and fallen out of use. The intention of a “cruise” clearance was to allow the pilot to climb or descend as required with the specific cruise altitude window. In your question that was 4000’-6000’. However, today people the same request would be made as “request an altitude block 4000-6000”. ATC would respond “(callsign) is cleared the block 4000 to 6000.” No further calls are required from you while maneuvering in that altitude block.
Sometimes a “cruise climb” clearance will be issued to heavy aircraft to allow them to climb slowly and level off for a while when they are too heavy to climb all the way to their final altitude. In that case they can climb as they are able but are not allowed to descend out of an altitude they have already climbed to.

Comment: Thanks, sir! Your examples are really helpful for me to understand.